# Как связаны win32crypt matplotlib и scipy?

Tags: python, python-3.5, cx-freeze

Для моего проекта нужен `win32crypt`. С библиотекой всё нормально, если я её компилирую напрямую с помощью python. Но я хочу скомпилировать свой проект в exe с помощью cx_Freeze. С этим тоже всё хорошо, но exe много весил, поэтому я решил убрать некоторые ненужные библиотеки:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

executables = [Executable('main.py')]

excludes = ['PyQt5', 'asyncio', 'botocore', 'bs4', 'cachetools', 'certifi', 'cffi',
            'charset_normalizer', 'concurrent', 'contourpy', 'cryptography',
            'curses', 'dearpygui', 'defusedxml', 'email', 'fontTools', 'fsspec',
            'google', 'html', 'http', 'idna', 'jinja2', 'kiwisolver', 'lib2to3',
            'logging', 'lxml', 'lz4', 'markupsafe', 'matplotlib.libs',
            'mpl_toolkits', 'mpmath', 'pandas', 'pandas.libs', 'scipy', 'scipy.libs',
            'psutil',
            'pyasn1', 'pyasn1_modules', 'pycparser', 'pydoc_data',  'pygments',
            'pyparsing', 'pytz', 'soupsieve', 'tcl8', 'tcl8.6', 'tkinter']

include_files = ['ps2exe.ps1', 'powershell']

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'include_msvcr': True,
        'excludes': excludes,
        'include_files': include_files
    }
}

setup(name='Sauron',
      version='0.0.98',
      description='I see you',
      executables=executables,
      options=options)
```

Однако, после запуска exe, python говорит что `win32crypt` не найден. Я решил попробовать убрать некоторые библиотеки из исключений, в итоге, пришёл к тому что всё работает вместе с `matplotlib` и `scipy`. Можно ли как-то добавить библиотеку `win32crypt` и при этом убрать библиотеки `matplotlib` и `scipy`?

Comment: Попробуйте установить pywin32, win32crypt по идее в этот пакет входит.

Comment: помогло, спасибо!